# How can I loop through an array with objects that contains an array in O(n) time?

Tags: javascript

This is an example of my data. I want to be able to iterate through each object then iterate through the contents and compare it with something. I was wondering how I can do it in O(n) time?

```
[
   {
     timeCreated: 'Mon Apr 05 2021 18:13:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
     _id: 606bb5af8f573f1edcb2098c,
     conversationID: 'nWdSPC3xoVta9BBISWnXZ3Gk',
     sender: 606b9712af2e6611dde79c63,
     contents: [ [Object] ],
     __v: 0
   },
   {
     timeCreated: 'Mon Apr 05 2021 18:41:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
     _id: 606bbc36cc470f20c64ebfc8,
     conversationID: 'nWdSPC3xoVta9BBISWnXZ3Gk',
     sender: 606b9712af2e6611dde79c63,
     contents: [ [Object] ],
     __v: 0
   }
]
```

Comment: Compare it with something? Do you have some sample code? What have you tried? What time do you think that sample code runs in?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just comparing 2 strings so it won't affect the runtime. I do not have sample code, but I'll set it up soon! The only solution I can come up with is O(n^2) using nested for loops.

Comment: I think you're confusing O(m*n) for O(n^2). Unless there's some other sorted quality to those contents arrays, you're there's no way you can not look at each element.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I confuse you, in case if you are looking to compare in two arrays then  you can try below.

For sure you must be having a common key between two arrays, so you can convert one array to object and read value by that unique key while iterating other array. Time complexity  would be **O(M + N)**

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, value: 'a'}, {id: 2, value: 'b'}, {id: 3, value: 'c'},{id: 4, value: 'd'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, value: 'x'}, {id: 4, value: 'y'}];

//converting arr1 to Object
const arr1Hash = arr1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

// loop second array based on your need
arr2.forEach(ele => {
  if (arr1Hash[ele.id]) {
    // perform rest of the work here if you find matching.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to look each element inside the `contents` property in 0(n) time.

But in this example will give you an idea on how you would do it on a different approach,

```js
let data = [
   {
     timeCreated: 'Mon Apr 05 2021 18:13:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
     _id: '606bb5af8f573f1edcb2098c',
     conversationID: 'nWdSPC3xoVta9BBISWnXZ3Gk',
     sender: '606b9712af2e6611dde79c63',
     contents: [ { id: 1, title: 'something' }, { id: 2, title: 'something 2' } ],
     __v: 0
   },
   {
     timeCreated: 'Mon Apr 05 2021 18:41:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
     _id: '606bbc36cc470f20c64ebfc8',
     conversationID: 'nWdSPC3xoVta9BBISWnXZ3Gk',
     sender: '606b9712af2e6611dde79c63',
     contents: [ { id: 3, title: 'something 3' }, { id: 4, title: 'something 4' } ],
     __v: 0
   }
];

// Select a data that contains the id = 1 in the contents property.
let selected_data1 = data.find(obj => obj.contents.find(content => content.id === 1))
console.log(selected_data1); // returns the 1st object

// Select contents of object that contains IDs (1,3)
let selected_data2 = data.reduce((a, b) => a = [...a, b.contents.find(content => [1,3].includes(content.id))], [])
console.log(selected_data2);  // returns [{ id: 1, title: 'something' }, { id: 3, title: 'something 3' }]

// Select all data but filter contents that contains IDs (1,3)
let selected_data3 = data.map(obj => ({...obj, contents: obj.contents.filter(content => [1,3].includes(content.id))}))
console.log(selected_data3); // returns all objects but filtered the contents property
```

Take can look into these functions, it'll be really useful to you: `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `sort`, `some`, `every`.